# Can't make my animated object follow a path

Tags: animation, path

I made a spider with a walk animation. I would like to make it follow a path, so I made a bezier curve and tried to do what I've seen in tutorials, but nothing works. In fact, I don't know which part of the spider I have to use: spider, armature, bones...? 
[image]

Here is the link of my blend file :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just parent the main parent object to the curve. Select the large circle then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the curve. Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> then choose "Object".

[image]

And... voilà:

[image]

Comment: Ok, it's working, but if then I want to scale the path, it's also scaling the spider...

Comment: Oh, I found. I have to extrude the last vertex of the curve :) Thanks a lot for your quick answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

**An alternative using drivers and fixed offset of path.**

*Got into this answer, got sidetracked, got answered, got accepted will post anyhow*

For walk cycles often like to use drivers and fixed offset of follow path. This will make switching paths simpler.

[image]

First recommend to Apply scale to your path

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
<kbd>A</kbd> Scale 
This will make your scale unity and not warp the spide.  Often strange behaviour filters from non uniform scale. If there is no reason not to have unit scale, make objects unit scale.

Set location of spider to (0, 0, 0), making  the follow path constraint place it at start of path.  Similarly to scale.  If something is going to follow path using offset method, without translation from the path to have its origin to be at one end of path at 0, and other at 1.

[image]

Forward of the spider is -Y axis.

Driven the offset of the follow path constraint (note it is **not** made the parent in this case).  *Can add other curves and step to next path animating constraint influence*

A simple driver to make the spider "walk" the whole path in 250 frames  *Note: Could keyframe instead*

```
frame / 250
```

can type this directly into field with no existing driver using `#frame / 250` The hash (`#`) tells blender to make expression a driver. Once a driver can edit directly in expression box.

Note: I'm using alpha version 2.83.8, and  for some reason this only works if curve radius is checked in modifier.  Didn't look too deeply into why. Believe in theory this should work without, may have something to do with the IK of the rig.

Very cool spider and rig btw.