# Path following via API

Tags: animation, scripting, constraints, path

Apologies if this question has been answered already, but I can't seem to get this thing working.

What I am trying to do is have a cube follow a curve interpolated out of coordinates. Manually this would be done selecting both curve and cube and selecting "follow path" constraint in the Ctrl + P menu.

I have have put together a short script, but when I run it, the curve has the cube as a child, and there is a follow curve constraint. But the cube is not centered on the curve, and pressing play will not do anything.

I believe that I might be missing something conceptual, but can't really figure out what that is.

Thanks!

````
import bpy

# Clearing scene
for item in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(item)

# Simulation Parameters
coords = [[0,0,0],[0,5,0],[0,0,15],[15,0,15], [0,0,20]]

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

# making curve
crv = bpy.data.curves.new('crv', 'CURVE')
crv.dimensions = '3D'

# initialize spline
spline = crv.splines.new(type='NURBS')

# a spline for each point
spline.points.add(len(coords)-1) # 1 point by default

# assign the point coordinates to the spline points
for p, new_co in zip(spline.points, coords):
    p.co = (new_co + [1.0]) # (add nurbs weight)
    
# make a new object with the curve
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('object_name', crv)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
obj.name = "Path" 

# Constraining Space craft to orbit
cube = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube'] 

#cube.parent = bpy.context.scene.objects['Path'] 
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='FOLLOW')

cube.constraints.new('FOLLOW_PATH')  #Constraining cubesat to follow the path 
cube.constraints['Follow Path'].target=bpy.data.objects['Path']
cube.constraints["Follow Path"].forward_axis = 'FORWARD_X'
cube.constraints["Follow Path"].use_curve_follow = True
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some tweaks.**

Took out the remove all objects, not a fan.

Use object references. After using an operator to add the cube

```
cube = context.object
```

after creating the curve `obj` it is known by reference as `obj`, no need to look it up as "Path".

When parenting via the operator, the selected objects are parented to the active. Have set the curve as active

```
context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
```

and selected the cube

```
cube.select_set(True)
```

before parenting via the operator.

Animate by setting an path duration (start to finish)  in frames on the curve object, and keyframing or driving the evaluation time.

See [Creating path curve using python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157892/creating-path-curve-using-python-script)  re using the end points of a nurbs curve

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

# Clearing scene
# IMO never add this to a question script.
'''
for item in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(item)
'''
# Simulation Parameters
coords = [[0,0,0],[ 0,5,0], [0,0,15],[15,0,15], [0,0,20]]

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=coords[0])
cube = context.object 
# making curve
crv = bpy.data.curves.new('crv', 'CURVE')
crv.dimensions = '3D'

# Animate the eval time (keyframes)
crv.path_duration = 250
crv.eval_time = 0
crv.keyframe_insert("eval_time", frame=1)
crv.eval_time = 10
crv.keyframe_insert("eval_time", frame=100)
crv.eval_time = 250
crv.keyframe_insert("eval_time", frame=250)
# initialize spline
spline = crv.splines.new(type='NURBS')
spline.use_endpoint_u = True
spline.use_endpoint_v = True
# a spline for each point
spline.points.add(len(coords)-1) # 1 point by default

# assign the point coordinates to the spline points
for p, new_co in zip(spline.points, coords):
    p.co = (new_co + [1.0]) # (add nurbs weight)
    
# make a new object with the curve
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('Path', crv)
context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
obj.select_set(True)
context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
cube.select_set(True)
#cube.parent = bpy.context.scene.objects['Path'] 
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='FOLLOW')

'''
cube.constraints.new('FOLLOW_PATH')  #Constraining cubesat to follow the path 
cube.constraints['Follow Path'].target = obj
cube.constraints["Follow Path"].forward_axis = 'FORWARD_X'
cube.constraints["Follow Path"].use_curve_follow = True
'''
```

**Fixed Position.**

Generally a user of fixed position and no follow path parenting. As shown in answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/169719/15543  With fixed position can keyframe or drive the offset, such that 0 is start of curve, and 1 is other end.

Comment: Thank you very much! And sorry for leaving the delete all objects line.